# Hash Function Opposite? Or a 2 way hash function?

Tags: function, hash, image-segmentation

I'm looking for a function that is similar to a hash in that it takes an input and gives a fixed number as the result. However I would like there to be a massive difference. This is not used for security but for data management.

I would like to make a function that can tell "similarity", does anyone know of a simple function that create similar databases given a file type?

Or is this only possible through machine learning and tagging?

For example, can you calculate a hash like code based on the input pixels of a random sized image, that was resized to 5x5 pixels, than go through again at 25x25, then again at 100x100, and 500x500. and 1000x1000, all while maintaining scale.

Perhaps each iteration of the function maps to different parts of the code?

5x5, 25x25, 100x100, 500x500, 1000x1000 each creates a 6 char string for example code and then they get added together:

123456-123456-654321-321456-231546 so what happens is that there is a dynamic record of visually similar things?

Anyway I am brainstorming now... Does anyone know of any existing functions that do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)?

Comment: Yep-- perfect, thanks so much!